# Cambiar entre Frames en Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz

Estoy intentando realizar una aplicación que comience en una ventana principal y pulsando un botón me lleve a otro frame distinto. El problema que tengo es que se me sobrepone un frame a otro y se ven cosas que no deberían aparecer en el frame 2 de la siguiente forma:
[image: Aquí solo debería verse el label "Ventana 2"]

Tengo este código:

```
import tkinter


raiz = tkinter.Tk()
raiz.title("Ventana Principal")
raiz.geometry("700x350")


def cambiar_ventana():
    ventana2 = tkinter.Frame(raiz).grid()
    etiqueta2 = tkinter.Label(ventana2, text="Ventana 2").grid(row=0, column=0)

ventana_inicial = tkinter.Frame(raiz).grid()
etiqueta_inicial = tkinter.Label(ventana_inicial, text="Ventana Inicial").grid(row=0, column=0)
btn_cambiar_ventana = tkinter.Button(ventana_inicial, text="Ventana 2", command=cambiar_ventana).grid(row=1, column=0)

raiz.grid()


raiz.mainloop()
```

He probado también con el método Toplevel() en la ventana 2 pero me crea dos ventanas diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

El problema de Toplevel() es que es una ventana dependiente de la primera, si se cierra la primera se cerrara también esa, para eso podemos usar Tk(), definiendo una función que cree la pestaña e indicando que cierre la primera cuando el botón sea pulsado usando la función .destroy(), el código quedaría así

```
import tkinter

def cambiar_ventana():
        ventana2 = tkinter.Tk()
        raiz.destroy()

raiz = tkinter.Tk()
raiz.title("Ventana Principal")
raiz.geometry("700x350")

ventana_inicial = tkinter.Frame(raiz).grid()
etiqueta_inicial = tkinter.Label(ventana_inicial, text="Ventana Inicial").grid(row=0, column=0)
btn_cambiar_ventana = tkinter.Button(ventana_inicial, text="Ventana 2", command=cambiar_ventana).grid(row=1, column=0)

raiz.mainloop()
```

Espero que te sirva, cualquier comentario es bienvenido.